# How to reverse a List of type DataRow?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a `List<DataRow>` which I need to use in DataTable. If to reverse the list it produces the error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building Example(dirty):
type 'ReversedListIterable<DataRow>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataRow>'
```

How to reverse a List of type `DataRow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<DataRow> listOfItems = [......];
List<DataRow> reversedListOfItems = listOfItems.reversed.toList()
```

this should do the trick